# Executing script at startup but remain in foreground for interaction-Linux

Tags: python, linux

I have a python script setup on a Raspberry pi (running raspbian) that needs to boot after startup and remain in the foreground as it requires interaction.  What I have now will execute the py script in the background.  I have made a file in etc/init.d with the following info:

```
#! /bin/sh

### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:        myService
# Required-Start: $ALL
# Should-Start: 
# Required-Stop:
# Should-Stop:
# Default-Start:  2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:
# Description:    service boot
### END INIT INFO

python /home/pi/Downloads/pythonTest.py
```

I can execute the "myService" script located in /etc/init.d from command line and my python script will run perfectly.  I made the myService script executable "sudo chmod u+x myService" and also updated rc.d "sudo update-rc.d myService defaults"

I have searched hours for the commands to keep my service in the foreground so that I can interact with script, with no luck.  If anyone can help, it would be great.

Comment: init scripts generally don't ever prompt for input, because they're designed to run unattened without a terminal - they're starting daemons, not user-interactive stuff. a misbehaving startup script (like one that prompts for input) can/will interrupt the entire boot sequence, forcing the system to wait for input that may never come.

Comment: You can't do this. This would interrupt the actual processes that expect to have the first user interaction, like login.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist I'm not a big linux guy, but could the startup process call another process after a time delay that would start in the foreground?

Comment: @Aaron I guess so but the time delay would just be your best guess, and trying to time it for "as soon as the user logs in" would be a disaster and definitely not portable to other systems if that was a concern. One way I could think to do this is that it could initiate a cron job that ran once after a specified amt of time.

Comment: Usually if you want something to happen at login you would run it as part of your login scripts, be that .bashrc or .xinitrc or whatever. If possible I would try to separate the parts of this that need to run during boot (init.d scripts) and the parts that need user feedback (login scripts).

Comment: I have tried everything to make this work. login scripts, LXDE-pi autostart, cron task @reboot, and I cannot get my script running with a terminal window running it in the foreground so that I can interact with it.  Is there any way I can get a script that simply runs:    "python /home/pi/myscript.py"    at startup and leaves the terminal window open with the script running?